# Change of basis for linear transformation - Linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

So I'm having a lot of difficulties with change of basis. Watched tons of tutorials on youtube but they only seem to confuse me more.

> Let $T: \mathbb{R^2} \to \mathbb{R^2}$ be defined by $T(a,b) = (a +
>  2b, 3a - b)$. Let $\mathcal{B} = \{(1,1),(1,0)\}$ and $\mathcal{C} =
> > \{(4,7),(4,8)\}$. Find $[T]_\mathcal{B}$ and $[T]_\mathcal{C}$ and
> show that $[T]_\mathcal{C} = Q^{-1} \cdot [T]_\mathcal{B}\cdot Q$ for
> some invertible matrix $Q$.

So I've done some thinking, and the matrix $Q$ might be the matrix that goes from basis $c$ to $b$? and then if I invert that one I get matrix $Q^{-1}$? I just have 0 idea where to start to problem from, like what's the first matrix that I have to work with?

Do I start with the basic basis in $R^2$ that is $\{(1,0),(0,1)\}$ and apply the transformation to it?

Comment: Take a look here for the general method to change basis https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2554999/how-do-i-express-ordered-bases-for-polynomials-as-a-matrices-linear-algebra

Comment: If you are ok, you can set as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Take a look here

[How do I express ordered bases for polynomials as a matrices? Linear Algebra.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2554999/how-do-i-express-ordered-bases-for-polynomials-as-a-matrices-linear-algebra)

In your case you know the matrix for the canonical basis:

$$T_A=\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 2 \\
    3 & -1 
    \end{bmatrix}$$

And two other basis:

$$\mathcal{B} = \{(1,1),(1,0)\}$$ and

$$\mathcal{C} = \{(4,7),(4,8)\}$$

and have to find the matrices $T_{B}$ and $T_{C}$ with respect these two basis.

You can follow the previous example to do it.

> Let's see for example **how to find** out $T_B$.

Let be $w$ any vector given in the canonical basis and indicate with: $v_1=(1,1)$ and $v_2=(1,0)$ the two vectors of the basis $\mathcal{B}$, also given with respect to the canonical basis.

We are loking for the coefficient $x_1$ and $x_2$ such that:

$$w=x_1\cdot v_1+x_2\cdot v_2$$

or in matrix form:

$$w=V\cdot x$$

$$V=\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 1 \\
    1 & 0 
    \end{bmatrix}$$

Note that $V$ contains as column the vectors of the new basis with respect to the canonical basis. It is important to note that $V$ represent the **matrix of change of basis** from $\mathcal{B}$ to the canonical.

Thus, the components of any vector $w$ with respect to the new basis are given by:

$$x=V^{-1}\cdot w$$

$$V^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 1 \\
    1 & -1 
    \end{bmatrix}$$

Thus $V^{-1}$ represent the **matrix of change of basis** from the canonical to the new basis $\mathcal{B}$ .

The mapping of $w$ with respect to the canonical basis is given by:

$$u=T_A\cdot w$$

Since we are looking for the matrix $T_B$ that represent $T$ with respect to the new basis  $\mathcal{B}$, let's plug in the change of basis:

$u=V \cdot y$

$w=V \cdot x$

to obtain:

$$u=T_A\cdot w \iff V \cdot y=T_A\cdot V \cdot x \iff y=V^{-1}T_A\cdot V \cdot x=T_B\cdot x$$

> Thus the matrix :

> $$T_B=V^{-1}\cdot T_A\cdot V$$

> represent the **transformation with respect to the new basis** $\mathcal{B}$.

For $T_C$ you can proceed in the same manner finding: $$T_C=W^{-1}\cdot T_A\cdot W$$ Now since $$T_B=V^{-1} \cdot T_A\cdot V \implies T_A=V \cdot T_B\cdot V^{-1}$$ you conclude $$T_C=W^{-1} \cdot T_A\cdot W=W^{-1} \cdot V \cdot T_B\cdot V^{-1}\cdot W$$

Comment: i did it again with the last formula you ended up with and i still don't get it. 

I used ( (1,3), (2, -1) ) as the matrix Ta. Multiplied first by V and then V^-1 and it gave me the matrix ( (2,1), (3,-2)). 

Now i do it in another way, by writing ( (1,3) ) as the linear combination of basis B and then (2,-1) as the linear combination of b, i end up with the matrix of change ( (3, -2), (-1,3) )

Comment: @Zimzim matrix ( (2,1), (3,-2)) you found is exactly $T_B$. To convince your self let's try to plug some vectors in the new base. For example $(1,0)_B$(which represent (1,1) in the Canonical. $T_B(1,0)_B=(2,1)_B$ wich is equal to $(3,2)_C$. Now try with $T_A(1,1)_C$ that is infactequal to (3,2). Let's try with any others vector! The matrix you have constructed expressing the columns of $T_A$ as l.c. of vactor basis of B should correspond to $V^{-1}T_A$, indded if you plug in a vector in the Canonical it returns the mapping expressed by the basis B. Let's try!

Comment: i see! so for Matrix V that you denoted is basically (Identity)b and v^-1 is the inverse of (Identity)b? by doing the multiplications, we end up with (T)b. I assume i would have to do the same thing for (T)c, meaning the V matrix would be {(4,7),(4,8)} and V inverse would simply be the inverse? Now to show the matrix Q in the problem, it's basically the matrice of change from C to be? Can i solve that with an augmented matrice and then compute the inverse to justify the equality? thank you so much.

Comment: For $T_C$ you proceed in the same manner finding: $$T_C=W^{-1}\cdot T_A\cdot W$$ Now $$T_B=V^{-1} \cdot T_A\cdot V \implies T_A=V \cdot T_B\cdot V^{-1}$$ thus $$T_C=W^{-1} \cdot T_A\cdot W=W^{-1} \cdot V \cdot T_B\cdot V^{-1}\cdot W$$

Comment: Thank you very very much gimusi, now it's finally clear in my head, thank you for your time and help and have an amazing day!