# How to express the basis $\beta = \{1, (x-1), (x-1)^2, (x-1)^3\}$ in matrix form

Tags: linear-algebra, change-of-basis

For a change of basis question, I have the following bases:

$$\epsilon = {1, x^1, x^2, x^3}$$ and $$\beta = {1, (x-1), (x-1)^2, (x-1)^3}$$

I believe that $\epsilon$ can be expressed as 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&0\\
0&1&0&0\\
0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

However, I am unsure on how to proceed with turning $\beta$ into a matrix. 
I have an attempt that translates to 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&0\\
0&(x-1)&0&0\\
0&0&(x-1)&0\\
0&0&0&(x-1)
\end{bmatrix}
$$
but I highly doubt that is correct.

Edit: I have checked this question here: [How do I express ordered bases for polynomials as a matrices? Linear Algebra.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2554999/how-do-i-express-ordered-bases-for-polynomials-as-a-matrices-linear-algebra)

but it lead me nowhere for my specific qualm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You expand the expressions and check the coefficients and put them in the right place in the matrix.

First column:
$$(1)\cdot 1$$
Second column:
$$1\cdot x +  (-1)\cdot 1$$
Third column:
$$(x-1)^2 = 1\cdot x^2 +  (-2)\cdot x + 1\cdot 1$$
Fourth column:
$$(x-1)^3 = 1\cdot x^3 +  (-3)\cdot x^2 + 3\cdot x + (-1) \cdot 1$$

$$\begin{bmatrix}1&-1&1&-1\\0&1&-2&3\\0&0&1&-3\\0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$