# Change of basis with linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

I've read [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2554999/how-do-i-express-ordered-bases-for-polynomials-as-a-matrices-linear-algebra)

article about changing of basis and everything looks pretty straightforward for me.
To change a basis we have to write input basis as a combination of output basis vectors.
In Gilbert Strang's book There is a chapter about change of basis which lists an example of basis change together with linear transformation which was an identity transformation. It says that we have first apply **linear transformation** to input basis, then columns of needed matrix are the coefficients of combination of output basis vectors of T(input). It's okay for me as well.
But the things I do not understand are:

1. If I already have a matrix of linear transformation *A* for example in standard basis and I want to make it to change a basis from input basis *$B_1$* to output basis *$B_2$* what should I do?
2. If I have the same matrix as above but it already changes a basis from *$B_1$* to *$B_2$* how can I make this matrix to change basis from *$B_3$* to *$B_4$*?

Comment: If you are given $B_1$ and $B_2$ , then you write each element of $B_{2}$ as a linear combination of elements of $B_1$ and the coefficients will give you the columns of the matrix that transforms $B_1$ to $B_2$. This matrix does not necessarily have any relevance to $B_3$ and $B_4$ . To convert $B_3$ to $B_4$ you need to do as you did for $B_1$ and $B_2$ .

Comment: However if $T$ transforms $B_{1}$ to $B_{2}$ and $S$ transforms $B_{2}$ to $B_{4}$. Then you can apply $ST$ to $B_{1}$ to get $B_{4}$.  Notice the difference in this case. I am assuming that $B_{3}=B_{2}$ and I have already figured out $S$, i.e the way to go from $B_{2}$ to $B_{4}$.

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron but If I have a transformation T, should I first apply this transformation to input bases? If I have a matrices $B_in$ and $B_out$ with bases, and also I have a matrix A for linear transformation which transforms 1 vector to another in standard basis, and I want to change it so it would take vectors those vectors from $B_in$ and transform them relative to $B_out$. $B_in$ - itself is a change of basis matrix from $B_in$ to standard, so I apply my T to $B_in$ first = A$B_in$, and then I write output vectors as a combination of $B_out$, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we write $[T]_A^B$ for the matrix of the linear transformation $T$ with respect to bases $A$ (for the domain) and $B$ (for the codomain), the general rule is $$[TS]_A^C  = [T]_B^C[S]_A^B.$$ The special cases where $S = I$ or $T = I$ (the identity transformation) are especially important.

To answer your questions:

1. If say $E$ is the standard basis and you know $[T]_E^E$, then for arbitrary $A,B$ you have $$[T]_A^B = [I]_E^B[T]_E^E[I]_A^E$$ by the rule above.
2. If you know $[T]_A^B$, then for arbitrary $C,D$ you have $$[T]_C^D = [I]_B^D[T]_A^B[I]_C^A$$

again by the rule above.

Comment: oh I see this path, from D to B, then B to A, then A to C

Comment: $[I]_A^E$ - is a change of basis matrix from A to E, or from E to A?

Comment: @Vanconts This terminology is a bit dangerous. The matrix $[I]_A^E$ changes the $A$-coordinates into $E$-coordinates (so it goes "from $A$ to $E$" in terms of coordinates), but its components are given by expanding the $A$ basis vectors in terms of the $E$ basis vectors (so it goes "from $E$ to $A$" in terms of bases).

Answer (score 3):

Okay, I don't know to what extent this might be helpful, but these are some notes I put together for my students when I was TA-ing linear algebra last year to help aid how you're supposed to think about this:

[image]
[image]
[image]